# sequelize - how to return plain object

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

I know this sounds like an easy request, but I have spent far too much time with this. By default, I want my output from sequelize to be a plain object, without any arrays.

I have previously used `raw: true`, but that will not work for this situation. I need to maintain the original tree. I have a complex result with 4 nested associations. There was a package from a developer called [sequelize-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-to-json), but after applying it to the most recent version of sequelize, I still had arrays within my object. I believe the plugin may no longer be supported, as the last commit was over a year ago.

Here is my model:

```
Namespace.findAll({
    attributes: ['namespace', 'description'],
    include: {
        model: Domain,
        as: 'domains',
        attributes: ['domain', 'description'],
        required: false,
        include: {
            model: Attribute,
            as: 'attributes',
            attributes: ['attribute', 'description'],
            required: false,
            include: {
                model: Value,
                as: 'values',
                attributes: ['type', 'value'],
                required: false,
                where: {
                    [Op.or]: [{ uuid }, { uuid: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' }],
                },
                // order: [['id', 'ASC']],
            },
        },
    },
})
```

Output is something like this:

```
[
{
    "namespace": "orangeApp",
    "description": "Mobile App Email Notifications",
    "domains": [
        {
            "domain": "notifications",
            "description": "Notifications",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute": "scheduled_medication",
                    "description": "Scheduled Medication",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "type": "delivery_method",
                            "value": "push"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "preview_type",
                            "value": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "attribute": "new_messages",
                    "description": "New Messages",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "type": "blahhhhhh",
                            "value": "true"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "attribute": "friend_requests",
                    "description": "Friend Requests",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "type": "dc",
                            "value": "true"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Preferred output would be something like this: (simplified to validate json)
    {
    "namespace": "orangeApp",
    "description": "Mobile App Email Notifications",
    "domains": {

```
    "domain": "notifications",
    "description": "Notifications",
    "attributes": {
        "attribute": "scheduled_medication",
        "description": "Scheduled Medication",
        "values": {
            "type": "delivery_method",
            "value": "push"
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? I have seen many examples where folks are getting pure JSON, but with my associations, and wanting to maintain the tree, I haven't seen a good example. All help is appreciated

Comment: Arrays are valid JSON elements...

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your query is going to only return an array with one object in it, you could use the findOne method instead of findAll. If you want to use what you have there, you could do the following:

```
let result = Namespace.findAll({
    attributes: ['namespace', 'description'],
    include: {
        model: Domain,
        as: 'domains',
        attributes: ['domain', 'description'],
        required: false,
        include: {
            model: Attribute,
            as: 'attributes',
            attributes: ['attribute', 'description'],
            required: false,
            include: {
                model: Value,
                as: 'values',
                attributes: ['type', 'value'],
                required: false,
                where: {
                    [Op.or]: [{ uuid }, { uuid: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' }],
                },
                // order: [['id', 'ASC']],
            },
        },
    },
})
let cleanResult = result[0].domains[0]
```

Only do this if you're only returning one result AND you're only interested in the first domain object in that domains property (which it seems as though you are).

To reinforce the comment you received, arrays are indeed valid JSON.